Stouffer's Method: Restriction on underlying hypothesis tests producing p values?
When using Stouffer's method to combine p values, they first have to be converted to z scores. Does this mean that p values that are derived for example from a permutation test are not valid inputs, because they are not based on z scores?

Stouffer's method does not assume that the p-values were obtained from z-tests / z-scores. It just makes use of the fact that if the null hypothesis is true for a particular test, then $p \sim \textrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ (ignoring any issues where model/test assumption are violated such that this is not exactly true), in which case $z = \Phi^{-1}(p)$ follows a standard normal distribution (where $\Phi^{-1}(\cdot)$ is the inverse cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution). This is true no matter what test was used to obtain the p-value.

Thank you. Just to clarify, Φ−1 here is the inverse CDF of the Normal, not of the Uniform. And to paraphrase your answer: The use of Z scores has nothing to do with the initial test statistics - it is simply used as a transformation to be able to work with a standard normal. Correct?

Correct - I've updated my answer to clarify this point.
